# PHP calculation function

Tags: php, excel

I made a calculation in Excel and am trying to use it in PHP. Unfortunately, I do not get the correct total when I'm using the function as I wrote it.

This is the calculation as I am using it in Excel :

```
2500 / (( 0.25 / 100 ) / ( 1 - ( ( 1 + ( 0.25 / 100 )) ^ -360)))
```

The function I made for calculating in PHP:

```
function calculatesum($income, $interestmonthly, $months){
   return $income / (( $interestmonthly / 100 ) / ( 1 - ( ( 1 + ( $interestmonthly / 100 ) ) ^ -$months)));
}
```

The function in PHP returns: '360000000' . But this should be '592.973,4538' .

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. Any tips will be welcome!

Already looked into the 'pow' functions, but still getting the same outcome.

Comment: what are you using "^" for in your code?

Comment: @user5237857 , the ^ is for the power of a number. (for example 2^5 = 2*2*2*2*2)

Answer (score 4):

Excel uses `^` for calculating the power of a number. PHP uses `pow($number, $exponent)` for that purpose.

```
function calculatesum($income, $interestmonthly, $months){
  return $income / (( $interestmonthly / 100 ) / ( 1 - ( pow(( 1 + ( $interestmonthly / 100 ) ), -$months))));
}

echo calculatesum(2500,0.25,360);
```

Output:

```
592973.4537607
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php for documentation and examples.

Comment: I see you probably solved the issue here so my answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Hey @maxhb many thanks for your solution. It works like a charm. I will look into the pow-function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. PHP does not raise power using ^. You can raise power of a value using

> **

For example,

> 2**5 will be equal to 2^5

Hope this helps.

```
function calculatesum($income, $interestmonthly, $months){
   return $income / (( $interestmonthly / 100 ) / ( 1 - ( ( 1 + ( $interestmonthly / 100 ) ) ** -$months)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't consider ^ as an operator, instead it uses another function **pow**.
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)
I think that is all you have to change to get the value you are looking for.

```html
function calculatesum($income, $interestmonthly, $months){ 
   $n1=( $interestmonthly / 100 );
   $n2= ( 1 + ( $interestmonthly / 100 ) );
   $r1= pow($n2,-$months);
   $r2=$n1 / ( 1 - $r1);
   return $income /($n1 /$r2);
}
```